# BoxView matrix in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently struggling with my project. The idea is to make few one row matrixes with variable length. In those matrixes I'll need change each boxView's color depends on the input. And apparently I got stuck in the begining of that project with creating matrixes. With following code I am able to make one or more matrixes and move it in the X direction, but no way can it move in Y. What am I doing wrong?

```
// BoxView dot dimensions.
double boxHeight = 1;
double boxWidth = 0.05;

public BoxView[,] rowPlaces(int count, double x, double y)
{
    BoxView[,] digitBoxViews = new BoxView[count, 1];

    // Create and assemble the BoxViews.
    double xIncrement = 0.035 ;
    double yIncrement = 0.03;

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < count; row++)
            {
                // Create the index BoxView and add to layout.
                BoxView boxView = new BoxView();
                digitBoxViews[row, col] = boxView;
                absoluteLayout.Children.Add(boxView,
                                            new Rectangle(x, y, boxWidth, boxHeight),
                                            AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
                digitBoxViews[row, col].Color = free;
                y += yIncrement;
            }

            x += xIncrement;
        }
        x += xIncrement;
    }
    return digitBoxViews;
}
```

In MainPage() I'm just calling this method, as I mentioned there should be like 16 of these matrixes [ whatever x 1] and also 2 columns [1 x whatever].

I'm new in Android and bit confused, I think the mistake is some basic?
Maybe wrong layout(currently using absoluteLayout)

[To make things more clear here is a picture of approximately layout I want to reach, each boxView should be reachable by name of matrix(vector) and it's index to change color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVE5N.png)

Comment: You question and code confused me, do you want a 16 * 2 rectangular matrix in `AbsoluteLayout`?

Comment: nah, I want to make matrix like 8x1, then 5x1 then 6x1 ..... and there will be 16 rows like that, I've edit the question so hope it makes things a bit more clear

Comment: Hi, can you show `boxWidth` and `boxHeight`? Are they int? like 10 or 5? If so, please change your `AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All` to `AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional`.

Comment: just editet, it's there. Problem is when I use Proportional everything dissapear and there is nothing on the screen Joe. Anyway thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: I think you need read [AbsoluteLayoutFlags](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/#Purpose), have you tested my codes? Is that picture the result you want?

Comment: not yet, but I'm going to test it. yes it is needed result.

Comment: Just tried your code and seems that I can reach my needs with that. I'll  play with that and let you know, also noticed that I had    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" in MainPage.xaml fromn some tutorial and it caused some troubles when testing your code, so I've put it away and now let's see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/) are many layouts you can choose, you can use any layout to achieve your goal, include [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/).

I have do something based on your codes:

`Layout`:

```
<AbsoluteLayout 
    x:Name="absoluteLayout"
    BackgroundColor="Yellow">

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

`MainPage`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rowPlaces(5, 0.2, 0.2);
    }

    public BoxView[,] rowPlaces(int count, double x, double y)
    {
        BoxView[,] digitBoxViews = new BoxView[count, 2];
        double sourcey = y;
        // Create and assemble the BoxViews.
        double xIncrement = 0.25 / count;
        double yIncrement = 0.5 / count;

        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < count; row++)
                {
                    // Create the index BoxView and add to layout.
                    BoxView boxView = new BoxView();
                    digitBoxViews[row, col] = boxView;
                    absoluteLayout.Children.Add(boxView,
                        new Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10),
                                                AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
                    digitBoxViews[row, col].Color = Color.Blue;
                    y += yIncrement;
                }

                x += xIncrement;
                y = sourcey;
            }
            x += xIncrement;
        }
        return digitBoxViews;
    }

}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, I've just managed what I needed and you became my personal hero haha unfortunately my vote for you can't be count. Need to work on my reputatuion I guess